# Coldfusion Email Handling

Tags: email, coldfusion

I am actually working on revamping an email component in my coldfusion app.
The component is pretty simple yet disorganised. 
Here is the way it is currently done :

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="ValidateVideoEmail">
        <cfargument name="userID" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="videoID" required="yes">

        <!--- Find video information --->
        <cfquery name="qryVideoInfo" datasource="#application.datasource#">
            SELECT ID
            ,NAME
            FROM tblVideo
            WHERE ID = #arguments.videoID#
        </cfquery>

        <!--- fetch email from active directory --->
        <cfldap filter="cn=#arguments.userID#"....name="qryMail">
        <cfmail from="noreply@mydomain.ca" to="#qryMail.mail#" subject="Video approved" type="HTML">
            <cfmailpart type="text/html"> 
                <span style="Bunch of css here">FRENCH VERSION / ENGLISH FOLLOW </span>
                <span style="Bunch of css here">Other part of message </span>
                <!--- there might be a link that redirects to a specific page on the website    or a query to find specific info such as the fullname of the user ... --->

            </cfmailpart>
         </cfmail>
    </cffunction>

<!--- Copy paste the above function, change arguments , change content of cfmailpart to what you need --->
 </cfcomponent>
```

Every function have different arguments and can call different queries. The email body also can be completely different based on what information is needed.

My problem is that I now have 3000 line of code in this component that only contains the function showed in the code above with different parameters.

Is there a way to optimise this component?
I tried adding the body of the email in a database and query the database but the cftags(IE: `<cfoutput>, <cfif> .`..) all display as text and are not processed by the server. It's a good solution when I only need to display pure text/css but it loses its purpose when using cftags...

Unless there is a solution to that that someone might enlighten me with!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If every function has a completely different body and produces different results, then it's rather difficult.

Recommendations:

- Don't repeat yourself. Turn every bit of code that exists more than once into a function.
- Break up stuff that is "almost but not quite" the same into separable parts.
- In short: Isolate the variable parts of your functions, abstract the fixed parts into helpers.
- Try to write functions that do exactly one thing and are only dependent on their arguments.
- Repeat until satisfied. Sometimes further abstractions become apparent later on.

Maybe this works as a push into the right direction.

```html
<cfcomponent output="no">
    <cffunction name="GetVideoInfo" returntype="query" access="private" output="no">
        <cfargument name="videoID" required="yes">

        <cfquery name="local.videoInfo" datasource="#application.datasource#">
            SELECT ID ,NAME
            FROM tblVideo
            WHERE ID = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.videoID#" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER">
        </cfquery>
        <cfreturn local.videoInfo>
    </cffunction>
    <!--- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ --->

    <cffunction name="GetUserInfo" returntype="query" access="private" output="no">
        <cfargument name="userID" required="yes">

        <cfldap name="local.userInfo" filter="cn=#arguments.userID#">
        <cfreturn local.userInfo>
    </cffunction>
    <!--- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ --->

    <cffunction name="SendEmail" returntype="void" access="private" output="no">
        <cfargument name="data" required="yes">

        <cfmail
            type="HTML"
            from="#data.mailFrom#" 
            to="#data.user.mail#"
            subject="#data.mailSubject#"
        >
            <--- you can use to #data.xyz# inside the include --->
            <cfinclude template="mailTemplates/#data.MailBody#.inc">
         </cfmail>
    </cffunction>
    <!--- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ --->

    <cffunction name="ValidateVideoEmail" returntype="void" access="public" output="no">
        <cfargument name="userID" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="videoID" required="yes">

        <cfset SendEmail({
            mailFrom: "noreply@mydomain.ca",
            mailSubject: "Video approved",
            mailBody: "ValidateVideo",
            user: GetUserInfo(arguments.userID),
            video: GetVideoInfo(arguments.videoID)
        })>
    </cffunction>
    <!--- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ --->

    <!--- more variants of the above --->
</cfcomponent>
```

Other notes:

- Always use `<cfqueryparam>`. Never build SQL by interpolating variable values right into it.
- Similarly, safeguard your LDAP search string against run-time syntax errors by escaping values properly (`userID` might contain [special characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx#Special_Characters) that will break the string if left unescaped - you need to write a function that escapes them)
- Externalizing the HTML bodies of the mails into includes helps with abstraction and readability by reducing the lines of code in your component.
- You might want to drop CF tags syntax in favor of [CF script syntax](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/extending-coldfusion-pages-with-cfml-scripting/defining-components-and-functions-in-cfscript.html) in the process. It would be a lot easier to read.

Comment: I'd actually abstract out the reading in of the mail body from the template as another function and then pass the read file content into `sendMail`. That makes `sendMail` do one job and it's then reusable without templates.

Comment: That's a matter of preference, but it would be one valid way to do it. I suppose the purpose of `SendEmail` is not to be the universal email sending function (that would be `<cfmail>` all over again), but it's tied to the purpose of the application anyway. A little tight coupling in this case can be argued for, IMHO.

Comment: I'm not saying you've posted a bad answer, just adding food for thought to the advice you've offered :) I'd only have one cfmail tag in my app in a MailService or something and would call that from anywhere that needs to send a notfication that way I can switch from a simple cfmail to using something like sendgrid in one place in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you could use `argumentcollection` and pass in how you expect to find your record.  Then use a `if(StructKeyExists(arguments.videoid)){}` statement to build the exact query you need to populate the email, construct the body in a `<cfsavecontent>` tag and only have one send statement at the end. It's still going to be long but you've reduced the duplicate content.